# Multiple Columns Dataset with And Operation in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

**Original Table Data**

[image: Original Table Data]

```
select 
DTRQLFR.DETERMINATION_ID_FK, DTRQLFR.QUALIFIER_ID_FK,   DTRQLFR.QUALIFIER_OPTION_ID_FK 
from IC_DTRMN_QLFR_XREF DTRQLFR
WHERE
(DTRQLFR.QUALIFIER_ID_FK, DTRQLFR.QUALIFIER_OPTION_ID_FK) IN ((1,1), (2,3), (3,6));
```

**Query Result**

[image: Query Result]

My requirement is need to apply **and** operation on dataset like below

```
   ((1,1) AND (2,3) AND (3,6))  ==> need to find  DETERMINATION_ID_FK as 1
   based on (DTRQLFR.QUALIFIER_ID_FK, DTRQLFR.QUALIFIER_OPTION_ID_FK) values
```

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: why can't you add `and DETERMINATION_ID_FK=1` ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok thanks for update, give me any idea, i tried but iam unable to find the solution

Comment: @SqlZim required to find DETERMINATION_ID_FK value based on given data sets

Comment: Based on datasets and result need to be find dynamicallay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to find the `dtrqlfr.determination_id_fk` that has all of the given sets. Something like this could work:

```
select 
  DTRQLFR.DETERMINATION_ID_FK
from IC_DTRMN_QLFR_XREF DTRQLFR
where
  (DTRQLFR.QUALIFIER_ID_FK, DTRQLFR.QUALIFIER_OPTION_ID_FK) IN ((1,1), (2,3), (3,6))
group by DTRQLFR.DETERMINATION_ID_FK
having count(*) = 3 -- where 3 is equal to the number of sets 
;
```

Comment: getting error-- ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: are you adding more columns to the select? http://rextester.com/GSS69787